# Is it possible for ADF project to reference another ADF project?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-factory

In my solution I have two Azure Data Factory projects: PR1 and PR2. PR1 contains definition of some resource - "resource1". In PR2 I have pipeline definition where I want to reference this resource as:

```
"linkedServiceName": "resource1"
```

When I try to build or publish PR2 I'm getting the error:

> Reference resource1 was not found in the solution

I tried adding PR1 to PR2 as a build dependency and as a reference, but error persists.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (version 14.0.25431.01) and Microsoft Azure DataFactory Tools for Visual Studio 0.9.3527.2.

Is it possible to have such dependencies between ADF projects? If yes, how can I set it up?

---

**Update:** I've figured out that `Script` item group is what's being compiled, so I've updated  `PR2.dfproj` file adding following target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" >
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Adding external dependencies"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Script Include="../PR1/resource.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

After that it's possible to build PR1, but when I try to 'Publish' it this target is not called, publishing fails on rebuild attempt.

Comment: What is the reason for needing to separate the ADF projects?

Comment: @PaulAndrew They are just different business cases, and there will be more of these in future

Comment: It be simpler just to have a single project with different ADF config files for each??

Comment: @PaulAndrew I don't understand how config could help in my scenario: I have completely different pipelines, which have different inputs, outputs, activities. I want to develop and deploy them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting up two separate Azure Data Factory instances, having one project for each. If not, set up copies of the linked services that are used in both projects.
MS is working on improving this area: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/6649781-allow-linking-one-factory-to-another

Comment: It's good to know, that MS is working on it (but looks like they are not in hurry - last update was in 2015). Having several ADF instances won't work for me in this case - we are already using several instances, but still need to deploy more than one project to some of them.